# previous item in a list ordered on two columns

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say we have a table with columns DAY and NUMERO.

There can be numerous rows with the same value of DAY but NUMERO is always unique.

What could be the most efficient way to get the item immediately preceding an existing couple (DAY, NUMERO) in a list ordered by DAY, NUMERO ?

I precise that I need this for mysql and I don't want to add a specific index (that's the reason why I don't simply use a linear function of DAY and NUMERO).

Here's an ordered test case :

```
DAY | NUMERO
1   | 11
1   | 12
1   | 15
4   | 7
4   | 9
4   | 14
5   | 8
6   | 10
6   | 19
```

My request must do this :

(1,11) => nothing

(1,15) => (1,12)

(4,7) => (1,15)

(4,9) => (4,7)

(4,14) => (4,9)

**EDIT :**

my current best solution is to have two successive queries :

```
select * from item where day=? and numero<? order by day desc, numero desc limit 1;

select * from item where day<? order by day desc, numero desc limit 1;
```

If the first query gives a result, I don't have to run the second one.

A similar solution would be to use a union but mysql doesn't seem to authorize unions with more than one column.

Both solutions look too heavy for a problem seeming so simple...

Comment: Well, you could select the max(numbero) for the same day, but with numberd smaller than the original.

Comment: That wouldn't give me (1,15) from (4,7). There's a moment I'm thinking and I don't see a unique trivial query.

Comment: I see. mysql does not have window-functions?

Comment: I don't think so but I'm not an expert in MySQL (nor any DBMS) so I'm maybe missing an easy solution.

Comment: Without window functions (row_number() rank() or lag()) or CTE's there is no easy solution. IMHO, you'll have to construct a nasty set of AND/OR clauses.

Comment: I think I can make an union from two select, each one having its own limit 1. But that's not pretty...

Comment: @wildplasser - postrgreSQL has window functions!

Comment: you mention you have come up with two solutions, why don't you post them so others don't duplicate your work?

Comment: I thought that "have two successive queries (one for the items on the same day and one for the items on a different preceding day if the first query didn't return anything)" was clear enough. I'm sorry. I'll detail them.

Comment: If NUMERO is unique, how come both (1,11) and (4,11) exist?

Comment: What is the point of not creating an index?

Comment: Rows do not typically have a logical connection to eachother--the data within does.  If you care about 'the row before', it surely seems like an autoincrementing ID is the best choice here; it may be two queries all the same, but the underlying logic "query row 5 = 4,9..match?!..query and return row 4!"

Comment: @hexparrot : the 11 duplicata was just an error. I typed this table for the explanation of the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only retrieving the previous pair based on a single pair as opposed to trying to do the entire table, as others have alluded to, you could try the following simple query -

```
:day = 4
:numero = 9

SELECT day, numero
FROM table
WHERE (day = :day AND numero < :numero)
OR (day < :day)
ORDER BY day DESC, numero DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I knew there had to be a simple solution. You know... I feel dumb now... You win.

Comment: It's easy to overlook the obvious when one over thinks the problem ;-)

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE**

Here is a solution that actually gives correct results!

```
 SELECT T1.day, 
       T1.numero, 
       COALESCE(MAX(T2.[day]), MAX(T3.[day])) AS prev_day,
       COALESCE(MAX(T2.numero), MAX(T3.numero)) AS prev_numero
FROM @table AS T1
LEFT JOIN @table AS T2 ON 
(
    T2.[day] = T1.[day] AND T2.numero < T1.numero
)
LEFT JOIN @table AS T3 ON  
(
    T3.[day] < T1.[day] 
    AND NOT EXISTS(
        SELECT * 
        FROM @table AS T4
        WHERE T4.[day] > T3.[day] AND T4.[day] < T1.[day]
    )
)
-- Add where clause like so to get specific values
-- WHERE T1.day = 4 AND T1.numero = 7
GROUP BY T1.day, T1.numero
ORDER BY T1.day, T1.numero
```

Results:

```
day         numero      prev_day    prev_numero
----------- ----------- ----------- -----------
1           11          NULL        NULL
1           12          1           11
1           15          1           12
4           7           1           15
4           9           4           7
4           11          4           9
5           8           4           11
6           10          5           8
6           19          6           10
```

Comment: Wrong. that's what I thought too at first. See second comment: "That wouldn't give me (1,15) from (4,7)"

Comment: This seems interesting (and I upvote you because I didn't event know the coalesce keyword before) but I don't understand how you use it (pardon me if I'm dense). What's the exact request to get the row just before (4,7) ?

Comment: @dystroy - docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce

Comment: @dystroy - to use this to get specific values, just add a where clause. i updated my answer to show this: `--WHERE T1.day = 4 AND T1.numero = 7`

Comment: That's really an interesting answer, but I wouldn't dare call it the best as it is really much to slow to be practical (even at second try with the same parameters it takes me more than 15 minutes on a table with less than 100 000 rows...)

Answer (score 1):

This is an vanilla query, avoiding CTE's, aggregates or window functions.

```
-- (a Before b) := (a.day < b.day
--               OR (a.day = b.day AND a.numero < b.numero))
SELECT d1.day AS DAY
        , d1.numero AS numero
        , d0.day AS day0
        , d0.numero AS numero0
  FROM tmp.lutser d1
  LEFT JOIN tmp.lutser d0
        ON (d0.day < d1.day OR (d0.day = d1.day AND d0.numero < d1.numero ))
  WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
     FROM tmp.lutser d
     WHERE (dx.day < d1.day OR (dx.day = d1.day AND dx.numero < d1.numero ))
       AND (dx.day > d0.day OR (dx.day = d0.day AND dx.numero > d0.numero ))
     )
ORDER BY day,numero
        ;
```

For reference, this is the query using window functions:

```
SELECT day
        , numero
        , lag(day) OVER (w1)
        , lag(numero) OVER (w1)
FROM tmp.lutser
WINDOW w1 AS (ORDER BY day, numero)
        ;
```

Result:

```
 day | numero | day0 | numero0 
-----+--------+------+---------
   1 |     11 |      |        
   1 |     12 |    1 |      11
   1 |     15 |    1 |      12
   4 |      7 |    1 |      15
   4 |      9 |    4 |       7
   4 |     11 |    4 |       9
   5 |      8 |    4 |      11
   6 |     10 |    5 |       8
   6 |     19 |    6 |      10
(9 rows)
```

Comment: +1 - She's pretty, I'll add that (in SQL Server at least) this one yeilds a better performing execution plan

Comment: The self-join-not-exist is one of my pet-peeves. Generates good plans, and will work on every platform I know of, probably because the idiom is very old / archaic.

Comment: Thank you for the insight but the problem is the same than with jcooper's answer : this is way to slow to be practical. Time on a real database (about 100 000 rows for example) is in minutes while my dumb two queries solution takes a few ms.

Comment: Your dumb two queries just retrieve the 2 values for 1 tuple. Cooper's and mine retrieve all the tuples. (but you can always add a restriction to the where clause).

Comment: I want one tupple, of course, as was said in question. And even with a where clause (that I added) it's very slow.